# Is there a way to make npm install (the command) to work behind proxy?

Tags: node.js, npm, proxy

Is there a way to make `npm install` work behind a proxy? I tried changing the proxy variable in the `.npmrc` file but it didn't  work. I'm trying to avoid doing a manual download.

Answer (score 417):

I solved this problem this way:

1. I run this command:

   ```
   npm config set strict-ssl false
   ```
2. Then set npm to run with http, instead of https:

   ```
   npm config set registry "http://registry.npmjs.org/"
   ```
3. Then I install packages using this syntax:

   ```
   npm --proxy http://username:password@cacheaddress.com.br:80 install packagename
   ```

*Skip the `username:password` part if proxy doesn't require you to authenticate*

EDIT: A friend of mine just pointed out that you may get NPM to work behind a proxy by setting ***BOTH*** HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY environment variables, then issuing normally the command  **npm install express** (for example)

EDIT2: As @BStruthers commented, keep in mind that passwords containing "@" wont be parsed correctly, if contains @ put the entire password in quotes

Comment: Heads up, if your password contains "@" npm won't parse your proxy setting correctly.  A potential workaround is to put a bogus username:password in the npm config, and use a local proxy (like fiddler) to modify the request's Proxy-Authorization header to have the correct username:password.  Keep in mind that the username:password stored in Proxy-Authorization is base64 encoded.

Comment: If your password contains an @ symbol, you can pass it by putting your username and password inside quotes.

Comment: I set the proxy with the username and password so you don't have to pass it as a parameter every time.  Good for a dev environment but wouldn't recommend in production without encryption considerations.

Comment: You can have special characters in your password, but they must be url-encoded. So if your password was `my@password`, your .npmrc file should have `my%40password`for the password part. Putting it in quotes works in some cases, but encoding it is foolproof.

Comment: any details about the setting evnironment variables way? thanks

Comment: Getting The requested URL /node-static was not found on this server

Comment: Another gotcha!  If you have previous set system variables **HTTP-PROXY** make sure you clear them!

Comment: For domain usernames in Windows it is needed to encode the \ char to `%5C`, so `domain\username` should be `domain%5Cusername`

Comment: @absynthemindedwebsmith `'username':'password'`? something like this?

Comment: Yep, although see the following comments for a better way.

Comment: How do i find my proxy address?

Comment: It is still not working. Please see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54787536/npm-etimedout-error-while-installing-react

Comment: This worked seamlessly though need to provide some username:"password"

Comment: You legend! I had given up on trying to get npm to work at work, but this finally resolved it.

Comment: I changed step 2 to use HTTPS protocol and it worked for me 

`npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/`

Comment: I have set up environment variables:

set HTTPS_PROXY=127.0.0.1:8080 set 

HTTP_PROXY=127.0.0.1:8080

Also, have set proxy values for npm: 

 npm config set proxy 127.0.0.1:8080 npm config set http-proxy 127.0.0.1:8080 npm config set https-proxy 127.0.0.1:8080. With these proxy settings I am not able to visit https pages

Comment: does this also allow access to `npx` ?

Answer (score 415):

Setup `npm` proxy

For `HTTP`:

```
npm config set proxy http://proxy_host:port
```

For `HTTPS`:

use the https proxy address if there is one

```
npm config set https-proxy https://proxy.company.com:8080
```

else reuse the http proxy address

```
npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
```

**Note**: The https-proxy doesn't have `https` as the protocol, but `http`.

Comment: Note that the https-proxy doesn't have 'https' as the protocol, but 'http'. Changing this solved the problem for me.

Comment: @peterhil Thanks for that tip. It's crazy but I spent hours to resolve this with "https". Any idea why it works like this?

Comment: @ManojNV, the connection to the proxy server isn't encrypted. It's not talking HTTPS to the proxy server, just HTTP. The payload is SSL between the client and the destination server. If it were HTTPS to the proxy server, then things would be getting encrypted/decrypted twice.

Comment: How do i find my proxy address?\

Comment: Thank you so much for all nice ideas from you guys here! I used command 1, 3 and then run this command `npm config set registry "http://registry.npmjs.org/"`. It worked :)

Comment: I have set up environment variables: set HTTPS_PROXY=127.0.0.1:8080 set HTTP_PROXY=127.0.0.1:8080 Also, have set proxy values for npm: npm config set proxy 127.0.0.1:8080 npm config set http-proxy 127.0.0.1:8080 npm config set https-proxy 127.0.0.1:8080. With these proxy settings I am not able to visit https pages

Answer (score 129):

When in doubt, try all these commands, as I do:

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
npm config set proxy http://myusername:mypassword@proxy.us.somecompany:8080
npm config set https-proxy http://myusername:mypassword@proxy.us.somecompany:8080
npm config set strict-ssl false
set HTTPS_PROXY=http://myusername:mypassword@proxy.us.somecompany:8080
set HTTP_PROXY=http://myusername:mypassword@proxy.us.somecompany:8080
export HTTPS_PROXY=http://myusername:mypassword@proxy.us.somecompany:8080
export HTTP_PROXY=http://myusername:mypassword@proxy.us.somecompany:8080
export http_proxy=http://myusername:mypassword@proxy.us.somecompany:8080

npm --proxy http://myusername:mypassword@proxy.us.somecompany:8080 \
--without-ssl --insecure -g install
```

=======

## **UPDATE**

Put your settings into `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` so you don't have to worry about your settings everytime you open a new terminal window!

If your company is like mine, I have to change my password pretty often. So I added the following into my ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile so that whenever I open a terminal, I know my npm is up to date!

1. Simply paste the following code at the bottom of your `~/.bashrc` file:

   ```
   ######################
   # User Variables (Edit These!)
   ######################
   username="myusername"
   password="mypassword"
   proxy="mycompany:8080"

   ######################
   # Environement Variables
   # (npm does use these variables, and they are vital to lots of applications)
   ######################
   export HTTPS_PROXY="http://$username:$password@$proxy"
   export HTTP_PROXY="http://$username:$password@$proxy"
   export http_proxy="http://$username:$password@$proxy"
   export https_proxy="http://$username:$password@$proxy"
   export all_proxy="http://$username:$password@$proxy"
   export ftp_proxy="http://$username:$password@$proxy"
   export dns_proxy="http://$username:$password@$proxy"
   export rsync_proxy="http://$username:$password@$proxy"
   export no_proxy="127.0.0.10/8, localhost, 10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/12, 192.168.0.0/16"

   ######################
   # npm Settings
   ######################
   npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
   npm config set proxy "http://$username:$password@$proxy"
   npm config set https-proxy "http://$username:$password@$proxy"
   npm config set strict-ssl false
   echo "registry=http://registry.npmjs.org/" > ~/.npmrc
   echo "proxy=http://$username:$password@$proxy" >> ~/.npmrc
   echo "strict-ssl=false" >> ~/.npmrc
   echo "http-proxy=http://$username:$password@$proxy" >> ~/.npmrc
   echo "http_proxy=http://$username:$password@$proxy" >> ~/.npmrc
   echo "https_proxy=http://$username:$password@$proxy" >> ~/.npmrc
   echo "https-proxy=http://$username:$password@$proxy" >> ~/.npmrc

   ######################
   # WGET SETTINGS
   # (Bonus Settings! Not required for npm to work, but needed for lots of other programs)
   ######################
   echo "https_proxy = http://$username:$password@$proxy/" > ~/.wgetrc
   echo "http_proxy = http://$username:$password@$proxy/" >> ~/.wgetrc
   echo "ftp_proxy = http://$username:$password@$proxy/" >> ~/.wgetrc
   echo "use_proxy = on" >> ~/.wgetrc

   ######################
   # CURL SETTINGS
   # (Bonus Settings! Not required for npm to work, but needed for lots of other programs)
   ######################
   echo "proxy=http://$username:$password@$proxy" > ~/.curlrc
   ```
2. Then edit the "username", "password", and "proxy" fields in the code you pasted.
3. Open a new terminal
4. Check your settings by running `npm config list` and `cat ~/.npmrc`
5. Try to install your module using

   - `npm install __`, or
   - `npm --without-ssl --insecure install __`, or
   - override your proxy settings by using `npm --without-ssl --insecure --proxy http://username:password@proxy:8080 install __`.
   - If you want the module to be available globally, add option `-g`

Comment: The last command worked for me. All the ones before that failed

Comment: i read about 50 answer concerning this fu***ing proxy configuration...the only that worked was your answer...thank you!!!

Comment: Thanks guys!! Glad it's working! This has been a huge headache at work so I'm glad i can help others out :P

Comment: +1. This works. I used commands- `npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/`, 
`npm config set proxy http://myusername:mypassword@proxy.us.somecompany:8080`, 
`npm config set https-proxy http://myusername:mypassword@proxy.us.somecompany:8080`, 
`npm config set strict-ssl false` for npm config and then installed npm package using `npm --proxy http://myusername:mypassword@proxy.us.somecompany:8080 
--without-ssl --insecure -g install {packagename}`.  Thanks

Comment: Primarily `--without-ssl --insecure` fixed the issue for `shasum` check error I was receiving on installing any package

Comment: Last one worked for me but without `__`, after i did reset all config to default config values.

Comment: After three days of trying this solution worked for me.

Comment: @MohanSingh so glad I could help! Sometimes you just gotta throw everything you have at the problem ;)

Comment: Hello! It is the most detailed answer, but it still didn't work for me. Please, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67127855/node-js-error-500-status-code-downloading-tarball

Comment: @Atur (and Katie and readers) you've succesfully installed a malware package now ;) Ok, not sure of that, but downloading a secretly forged package and then failing on a shasum check error might be serious. Please don't suggest that. Its like telling others to disable virusscanners when downloading malware from a phishing site.

Answer (score 39):

Have you tried command-line options instead of the `.npmrc` file?

I think something like `npm --proxy http://proxy-server:8080/ install {package-name}` worked for me.

I've also seen the following:
`npm config set proxy http://proxy-server:8080/`

Comment: +1 i tried the others this was the one that worked for me. with the auth part from Renato Gama

Comment: I have set up environment variables: set HTTPS_PROXY=127.0.0.1:8080 set HTTP_PROXY=127.0.0.1:8080 Also, have set proxy values for npm: npm config set proxy 127.0.0.1:8080 npm config set http-proxy 127.0.0.1:8080 npm config set https-proxy 127.0.0.1:8080. With these proxy settings I am not able to visit https pages

Answer (score 23):

Though there are already many good advice, for my environment(Windows 7, using PowerShell) and the last version available of node.js ( v8.1.2 ) all the above did not worked, except when I followed [brunowego](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9401#issuecomment-233606470) settings.

So check your settings with :

```
npm config list
```

Settings behind a proxy:

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
npm config set http-proxy http://username:password@ip:port
npm config set https-proxy http://username:password@ip:port
npm config set proxy http://username:password@ip:port
npm set strict-ssl false
```

Hope this will save time to someone

Comment: how do i find my proxy address?

Comment: @Robin One way, if using windows, IE stores them. You can go under IE and view LAN settings under connection, and it will show it there.

Comment: @Robin of course depends on the browser, but usually is under settings

Comment: @Robin in the browers under setting you should see / check proxy setting. Usually there is a file with .pac where last like should be : PROXY YourProxyAdress:PORT

Comment: I have set proxy values for npm: npm config set proxy 127.0.0.1:8080, npm config set http-proxy 127.0.0.1:8080 , npm config set https-proxy 127.0.0.1:8080. With these proxy settings I am not able to visit https pages

Comment: @Yatin Kanyal because indeed the setting is "http-proxy" try with "https-proxy" as I wrote above.

Answer (score 19):

This works for me in Windows:

```
npm config set proxy http://domain%5Cuser:pass@host:port
```

If you are not in any domain, use:

```
npm config set proxy http://user:pass@host:port
```

If your password contains special characters such as `"`,`@`,`:` and so on, replace them by their URL encoded values. For example `"`->`%22`, `@`->`%40`, `:`->`%3A`. `%5C` is used for the character `\`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, this worked for me. You can open up your javascript console with ctrl+shift+j and type `encodeURIComponent("YourP@ssword")` to get the encoded version of your password.

Comment: I have set proxy values for npm: npm config set proxy 127.0.0.1:8080, npm config set http-proxy 127.0.0.1:8080 , npm config set https-proxy 127.0.0.1:8080. With these proxy settings I am not able to visit https pages

Comment: Is your proxy on localhost (127.0.0.1)?

Answer (score 16):

To setup the http proxy have the **-g** flag set:

`sudo npm config set proxy http://proxy_host:port -g`

For https proxy, again make sure the **-g** flag is set:

`sudo npm config set https-proxy http://proxy_host:port -g`

Comment: what is the meaning of -g?

Comment: sets it up globally, not for the local installation

Comment: I have set proxy values for npm: npm config set proxy 127.0.0.1:8080, npm config set http-proxy 127.0.0.1:8080 , npm config set https-proxy 127.0.0.1:8080. With these proxy settings I am not able to visit https pages . I tried with -g also

Answer (score 11):

Finally i have managed to solve this problem being behinde proxy with AD authentication. I had to execute:

```
npm config set proxy http://domain%5Cuser:password@proxy:port/
npm config set https-proxy http://domain%5Cuser:password@proxy:port/
```

It is very important to URL encode any special chars like backshlash or # 
In my case i had to encode

1. `backshlash` with %5C so `domain\user will` be `domain%5Cuser`
2. `#` sign with `%23%0A` so password like `Password#2` will be `Password%23%0A2`

I have also added following settings:

```
npm config set strict-ssl false
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Comment: I have set proxy values for npm: npm config set proxy 127.0.0.1:8080, npm config set http-proxy 127.0.0.1:8080 , npm config set https-proxy 127.0.0.1:8080. With these proxy settings I am not able to visit https pages

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me-

```
npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
npm set strict-ssl=false
```

Comment: I have set proxy values for npm: npm config set proxy 127.0.0.1:8080, npm config set http-proxy 127.0.0.1:8080 , npm config set https-proxy 127.0.0.1:8080. With these proxy settings I am not able to visit https pages

Answer (score 8):

```
$ npm config set proxy http://login:pass@host:port
$ npm config set https-proxy http://login:pass@host:port
```

Comment: Add some comments please.

Answer (score 7):

Though i set proxy with config, problem was not solved but after
This one worked for me:

> npm --https-proxy http://XX.AA.AA.BB:8080 install cordova-plugins
>
> npm --proxy http://XX.AA.AA.BB:8080 install

Comment: This one work for me , no other change . Open command window and use above and it will work

Answer (score 7):

`vim ~/.npmrc` in your Linux machine and add following. Don't forget to add `registry` part as this cause failure in many cases.

```
proxy=http://<proxy-url>:<port>
https-proxy=https://<proxy-url>:<port>
registry=http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Comment: Many proxies support tunneling https requests, but they will not handle a https connection to themselves. As such, when running into trouble, try modifying `https-proxy=https://..` into `https-proxy=http://..`

Answer (score 7):

```
npm config set proxy <http://...>:<port_number>
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

This solved my problem.

Comment: The crucial thing was to change the link to the registry: instead of https I had before to http link.

Answer (score 6):

I tried all of these options, but my proxy wasn't having any of it for some reason. Then, born out of desparation/despair, I randomly tried `curl` in my Git Bash shell, and it worked.

Unsetting all of the proxy options using

```
npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https-proxy
```

And then running `npm install` in my Git Bash shell worked perfectly. I don't know how it's set up correctly for the proxy and the Windows `cmd` prompt isn't, but it worked.

Answer (score 6):

On Windows system

Try removing the proxy and registry settings (if already set) and set environment variables on command line via

```
SET HTTP_PROXY=http://username:password@domain:port
SET HTTPS_PROXY=http://username:password@domain:port
```

then try to run npm install. By this, you'll not set the proxy in .npmrc but for that session it will work.

Comment: This worked for me. The equals symbol is what seemed to get it all to work. Before that I was just using ```SET HTTP_PROXY http://username:password@domain:port``` but switching to ```SET HTTP_PROXY=http://username:password@domain:port``` seemed to get everything working

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I forgot to set the "http://" in my config files (can be found in C: \Users \ [USERNAME] \ .npmrc) proxy adresses. So instead of having

```
proxy=http://[IPADDRESS]:[PORTNUMBER]
https-proxy=http://[IPADDRESS]:[PORTNUMBER]
```

I had

```
proxy=[IPADDRESS]:[PORTNUMBER]
https-proxy=[IPADDRESS]:[PORTNUMBER]
```

Which of course did not work, but the error messages didnt help much either...

Answer (score 6):

After tying different answers finally, @Kayvar answers's first four lines help me to solve the issue:

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
npm config set proxy http://myusername:mypassword@proxy.us.somecompany:8080
npm config set https-proxy http://myusername:mypassword@proxy.us.somecompany:8080
npm config set strict-ssl false
```

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me.
Set the http and https proxy.

- npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
- npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080

Answer (score 5):

For me even though python etc will all work though our corporate proxy npm would not.

I tried

`npm config set proxy http://proxyccc.xxx.ca:8080
npm config set https-proxy https://proxyccc.xxx.ca:8080
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/`

as instructed but kept getting the same error.

It was only when I **removed**
`https-proxy https://proxyccc.xxx.ca:8080`
from the .npmrc file 
that 
npm install electron --save-dev worked

Comment: Your `https-proxy` is probably not `https:`.  At least, having the same port for each is probably not correct, but I think they both probably have the same value.

Answer (score 5):

*There is good information on curl's page on [SSL and certificate issues](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html).
I base most of my answer on the information there.*

Using strict-ssl false is bad practice and can create issues. What we can do instead is add the certificate that is being injected, by the "man in the middle" certificate.

How to solve this on Windows:

1. Download the CA Certificates from [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html) based on Mozilla's CA bundle. You can also use curl's "firefox-db2pem.sh" shellscript to convert your local Firefox database.
2. Go to a webpage using https, for example [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com) in Chrome or Internet Explorer
3. Click the lock icon, click View certificates or "Valid" in Chrome
4. Navigate to the Certification path. The top certificate, or the root certificate is the one we want to extract. Click that certificate and then "view certificate"
5. Click the second tab, "Details". Click "Copy to file". Pick the DER format and make note of where you save the file. Pick a suitable filename, like rootcert.cer
6. If you have Git installed you will have openssl.exe. Otherwise, install git for windows at this stage. Most likely the openssl executable will be at C:\Program Files\git\usr\bin\openssl.exe. We will use openssl to convert the file to the PEM format we need for NPM to understand it.
7. Convert the file you saved in step 5 by using this command:
   `openssl x509 -inform DES -in **rootcert**.cer -out outcert.pem -text`
   where **rootcert** is the filename of the certificate you saved in step 5.
8. Open the outcert.pem in a text-editor smart enough to understand line-endings, so not notepad.
9. Find -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- *lots of characters* -----END CERTIFICATE----- and copy all text between them and also including the BEGIN / END lines
10. Now we will paste that content to the end of the CA Cert bundle made in step 1. So open the **cacert.pem** in your advanced texteditor. Go to the end of the file and paste the content from previous step to the end of file. (Preserve the empty line below what you just pasted)
11. Copy the saved cabundle.pem to a suitable place. Eg your %userprofile% or ~. Make note of the location of the file.
12. Now we will tell npm/yarn to use the new bundle. In a commandline, write
    `npm config set cafile **C:\Users\username\cacert.pem**`
    where **C:\Users\username\cacert.pem** is the path from step 10.
13. Optionally: turn on strict-ssl again, `npm config set strict-ssl true`

Phew! We made it! Now npm can understand how to connect. Bonus is that you can tell curl to use the same cabundle.pem and it will also understand HTTPs.

Comment: via commands: `echo | openssl s_client -showcerts -servername www.domain.com -connect www.domain.com:443 2>/dev/null | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > cacert.crt` to get the `crt` file first; And then generate the pem file via: `openssl x509 -inform PEM -in cacert.crt -out cert.pem -text`; And add pem file into npm cafile via: `npm config set cafile /path/to/cert.perm`

Answer (score 4):

Use below command at cmd or GIT Bash or other prompt

$ npm config set proxy "http://192.168.1.101:4128"

$ npm config set https-proxy "http://192.168.1.101:4128"

where 192.168.1.101 is proxy ip and 4128 is port. change according to your proxy settings. its works for me.

Comment: I got to use a domain for authentication, and I used escaped back-slash: with this string %5C . It worked finally!

Answer (score 4):

Try to find .npmrc in C:\Users\.npmrc

then open (notepad), write, and save inside :

```
proxy=http://<username>:<pass>@<proxyhost>:<port>
```

PS : remove "<" and ">" please !!

Answer (score 4):

A lot of applications (e.g. npm) can use proxy setting from user environment variables.

You can just add to your environment following variables **HTTP_PROXY** and **HTTPS_PROXY** that will have the same value for each one

http://user:password@proxyAddress:proxyPort

For example if you have Windows you can add proxy as follow:

[image: How it looks on Windows]

Answer (score 4):

There has been many answers above for this question, but none of those worked for me. All of them mentioned to add `http://` prefix. So I added it too. All failed.

It finally works after I accidentally removed `http://` prefix. Final config is like this:

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
npm config set http-proxy ip:port
npm config set https-proxy ip:port
npm config set proxy ip:port
npm set strict-ssl false
```

I don't know the logic behind this, but it worked. If none of answers above works for you, maybe you can have a try on this way. Hope this one is useful.

Answer (score 4):

Here are the steps that I've followed (Windows):

1. Edit the following file `C:\Users\<WIN_USERNAME>\.npmrc`
2. Export the certificate to your file system from the following address:https://registry.npmjs.org
3. Navigate to the exported certificate location and issue the following command:

   `npm config set cafile npm_certificate.cer`
4. Add the following changes to the file:
   `registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
   strict-ssl=false
   https-proxy=http://[proxy_user]:[proxy_password]@[proxy_ip]:[proxy_port]/
   cafile=npm_certificate.cer`

Now you should be ready to go!

Answer (score 4):

Just open the new terminal and type `npm config edit` and `npm config -g edit`. Reset to defaults. After that close terminal, open the new one and type `npm --without-ssl --insecure --proxy http://username:password@proxy:8080 install <package>` if you need globally just add `-g`.

It worked for me, hope it`ll work for you :)

Answer (score 2):

when I give without http/http prefix in the proxy settings npm failed even when the proxy host and port were right values. It worked only after adding the protocol prefix.

Answer (score 2):

My issue came down to a silly mistake on my part.  As I had quickly one day dropped my proxies into a windows *.bat file (http_proxy, https_proxy, and ftp_proxy), I forgot to escape the special characters for the url-encoded domain\user (%5C) and password having the question mark '?' (%3F).  That is to say, once you have the encoded command, don't forget to escape the '%' in the bat file command.

I changed

```
set http_proxy=http://domain%5Cuser:password%3F@myproxy:8080
```

to

```
set http_proxy=http://domain%%5Cuser:password%%3F@myproxy:8080
```

Maybe it's an edge case but hopefully it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

Go TO Environment Variables and Either Remove or set it to empty

**HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY**

it will resolve proxy issue for corporate env too

Answer (score 1):

to use proxy in npm install **forget all the npm config stuffs** and just simply **set a http proxy in proxy environment** variables and then do the `npm i`

```
export https_proxy=http://proxy.address.com:1090/
export http_proxy=http://proxy.address.com:1090/
```

this always works for me.

im not sure why but npm seems like doesn't works well with socks proxies but it works great with http proxies.

Answer (score 1):

So many answers and most of them are the same. My problem was, it is working fine when I am connected to the VPN of my company or working in my office, but it fails when I am using public internet connection.

When you set the `proxy` (and/or `https-proxy`) option and you temporarily like to disable it for whatever reason, then run

```
npm --noproxy "registry.npmjs.org" install <package>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just have have my share of fight with npm and proxy settings and since I do not like other answers I like to share how I think this should be resolved (compromising security is not an option).

### What docs says

First of all you have to be aware what are important settings available for `npm` related to proxy:

- [`proxy`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/config#proxy) A proxy to use for outgoing http requests. If the HTTP_PROXY or http_proxy environment variables are set, proxy settings will be honored by the underlying request library.
- [`https-proxy`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/config#https-proxy) A proxy to use for outgoing https requests. If the HTTPS_PROXY or https_proxy or HTTP_PROXY or http_proxy environment variables are set, proxy settings will be honored by the underlying request library.
- [`noproxy`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/config#noproxy) A comma-separated string or an array of domain extensions that a proxy should not be used for.
- [`cafile`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/config#cafile) A path to a file containing one or multiple Certificate Authority signing certificates. Similar to the ca setting, but allows for multiple CA's, as well as for the CA information to be stored in a file on disk.

Now since default values for `proxy`, `https-proxy` are based on environment variables it is recommended way to properly configure those variables so other tools could work too (like `curl`).

Note that for v6 `noproxy` documentation doesn't say anything about environment variables and [since v7](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/config#noproxy) NO_PROXY environment variable is mentioned. My environment
wasn't configured to verify how this variable works (if lower case version is covered).

### Proper configuration

Now I was configuring docker image which should be used behind a proxy and this entries were needed in Dockerfile:

```
COPY certs/PoroxyCertificate.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
COPY certs/RootCa.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
RUN update-ca-certificates
# here all tools like curl were working

RUN  ["/bin/bash", "-c", "set -o pipefail && curl -sSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x  |  bash -"]
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y nodejs
RUN npm config set cafile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt -g
```

Now interesting thing is that I needed two certificate files. `RootCa.crt` is self signed certificate for all corporate servers and `PoroxyCertificate.crt` contains that certificate, but it also has an extra middle SubCA certificate. Proxy was responding with certificate chain of length 3.

Now `update-ca-certificates` scans directory `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/` for new certificates and updates `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` which will contain much more then those custom certificates.

Feeding this `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` to `cafile` of `npm config` resolve all problems with certificates when proxy was used.

### Important note

with npm v6 certificate errors quite often lead to `npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded` what is very confusing (I even broke certificate on purpose to verify this issue), log file contained something like this:

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at isDepOptional (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:417:24)
    at failedDependency (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:441:9)
    at failedDependency (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:9)
    at failedDependency (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:9)
    at failedDependency (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:9)
    at failedDependency (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:9)
    at failedDependency (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:9)
    at failedDependency (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:9)
    at failedDependency (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:9)
    at failedDependency (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:9)
    at failedDependency (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:9)
    at failedDependency (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:9)
    at failedDependency (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:9)
    at failedDependency (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:9)
    at failedDependency (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:9)
    at failedDependency (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:9)
```

I've found some some [issue about that](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/1918), but this will not be fixed in v6.