# locally installing node npm packages

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I am accessing internet under the wifi network(cyberoam) provided by our college. Whenever I am trying to install any npm package I am getting error like:

> npm ERR! If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
>
> > npm ERR! 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
>
> ECONNREFUSED

I haven't set up any proxies on my Linux machine then also I'm getting error like this.
Is there any way to install those packages locally i.e how can I use them directly without installing them as npm packages.

Comment: Maybe you are behind a proxy even without knowing. In this case you may want to configure proxy settings for NPM, this thread might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559648/is-there-a-way-to-make-npm-install-the-command-to-work-behind-proxy/13138231#13138231

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible but I usually don't do that. For a quick and dirty solution:

- Search for the packages repos in github
- Checkout them to your local machine
- And copy each one to the ./node_modules directory inside your node.js application folder.

In the future I certainly recommend you to use npm instead.