# Grunt installation failure

Tags: node.js, npm, gruntjs

I am trying to install Grunt on the machine at work. I have already successfully installed Node.JS and configured the proxy (with `npm config set proxy` as well as the https-proxy). I have also tried the solution over here: [Is there a way to make npm install (the command) to work behind proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559648/is-there-a-way-to-make-npm-install-the-command-to-work-behind-proxy)

This is the error I get:

```
http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-cli
silly lockFile d63f3d0b-grunt-cli grunt-cli@
silly lockFile d63f3d0b-grunt-cli grunt-cli@
error Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=Parse Error
error     at ClientRequest.onError (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\node_modules\tunnel-agent\index.js:159:17)
error     at ClientRequest.g (events.js:175:14)
error     at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
error     at Socket.socketOnData (http.js:1558:9)
error     at TCP.onread (net.js:525:27)
```

What should I do in order to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution which worked for me was to set the registry from https to http:

```
$ npm config set http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have tried `npm config edit` and set `registry = http://registry.npmjs.org/`. I do no longer get the same error, now it is a 404 Not Found status. `The requested URL /grunt-cli was not found on the server.` So I get a html page instead a JSON response. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: OK. I have changed the proxy to another one and it seems to be working now(at least with the solution you suggested. I do not know why the other proxy did not work. Thank you!