# npm not working behind proxy

Tags: node.js, proxy, npm

I am trying to do a 'npm install express' on my machine. All my internet access is via proxy which requires authentication. I am trying the following command to set the proxy and then do the npm install but still its not working.

```
npm config set proxy=http://<username>:<password>@<ip>
npm install express
```

here,
    username->myinternet
    password->abcd#1234
    ip->192.168.32.62:3128

What am i missing here?

I have also tried various other combination like npm --proxy  -g install express  and also with --without-ssl --insecure.

I am totally stuck here and am unable to proceed. Is there a problem with the password abcd#1234. I read somewhere that '@' character in passwords are not processed correctly. Is it the same with '#' character too? By the way I tried passing username:password in a string literal too, but without any success.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559648/is-there-a-way-to-make-npm-install-the-command-to-work-behind-proxy?rq=1

Comment: i had seen that link before submitting the question. Unfortunately I have already tried all the tricks mentioned in the thread.

Comment: can somebody please help?

Comment: What is "not working"?

Comment: Also,  make sure you're using the HTTP vs HTTPS registry: `npm config set registry=http://registry.npmjs.org/`

Comment: unfortunately joe, i have set registry also and desspite of that it is not installing packages. It still says "npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'" . Not sure why its not reading proxy settings although npm get proxy displays correct settings.