# Cannot install yo in npm

Tags: node.js, npm, yeoman

I am trying to build an application using yeoman

I tried to install yo in npm-node.js

npm install -g yo and I had set the proxy also.

But I get the following Error:

```
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm http GET https://github.com/Filirom1/nopt/tarball/master#pull-request-in-progress
npm ERR! fetch failed https://github.com/Filirom1/nopt/tarball/master#pull-request-in-progress
npm ERR! Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.onError (C:\Users\584042\Documents\tools\nodejs\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\tunnel.js:161:17)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.g (events.js:175:14)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
npm ERR!     at Socket.socketErrorListener (http.js:1499:9)
npm ERR!     at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
npm ERR!     at net.js:426:14
npm ERR!     at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Users\\584042\\Documents\\tools\\nodejs\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\584042\\Documents\\tools\\nodejs\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.j
"-g" "yo"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\584042\Documents\tools\nodejs\nodejs
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.7
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.14
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\584042\Documents\tools\nodejs\nodejs\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Please Advice

Comment: Are you running under Linux?

Comment: Nope.I am running in Windows

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559648/is-there-a-way-to-make-npm-install-the-command-to-work-behind-proxy

Comment: I did according to those instructions as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559648/is-there-a-way-to-make-npm-install-the-command-to-work-behind-proxy                                                             But didnt help

Comment: I have set the registry also.npm config set registry="http://registry.npmjs.org/"

Comment: Seems to be an open issue: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/4529