# How to know the proxy url in linux?

Tags: linux, proxy, npm

I know is a noob question but how can I know the proxy url and other settings in order to use a proxy? I don't have any information about proxy right now.

I need npm to run in linux like explained here: [Is there a way to make npm install (the command) to work behind proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559648/is-there-a-way-to-make-npm-install-the-command-to-work-behind-proxy) but they say

```
npm config set proxy http://myusername:mypassword@proxy.us.somecompany:8080
```

So what is the `myusername` and `mypassword`, the username and password to login in the machine or what else? `proxy.us.somecompany:8080` what is mine and how can I find it?

Thanks, and sorry for the newbie question but I can't find the answer.

Comment: I'm less than a newbie on this so forgive me if this comment is clueless or off base.  It looks as if this discussion pertains to you using npm as a user on a local network, one that is protected by a proxy server.  If this is the case, I'd work with your network administrator to set this up.  If I were that administrator, I'd proceed carefully to avoid opening up a security hole, hopefully using https rather than http and in any event setting up a special purpose account to limit damage (and signal an alarm) should it be compromised.  Please don't use your username, password and domain.

Comment: System Admin is not reachable.

Comment: That's unfortunate.  I don't know your shop, its rules, or politics.  If this task is mission critical, you may need to exert pressure to get some sort of network admin help.  Otherwise, patience might be the approach to use.

Comment: I was thinking that I could solve by myself...

Comment: If you're familiar with the Spielberg comedy _1941_ and read my first comment you may have something to work with.  I don't recommend it, and don't even know that it will work, but it might.