# sudo npm install -g ionic on Mac

Tags: node.js, npm, ionic-framework

I am able to install node on mac  and cordova

When I run

```
node -v
```

it gives v0.12.2.

and `npm -v` is 2.7.4

and `cordova -v` is 5.0.0.

Now I tried `sudo npm install -g ionic`
it gives me error

> network read ECONNRESSET
>
> network if you are behind the proxy , please make sure that the proxy
>   and so on

I have no idea how to set a proxy.

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559648/is-there-a-way-to-make-npm-install-the-command-to-work-behind-proxy/10304317#10304317

Comment: Yes, i tried same solution as well. Still getting same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having same problem on Windows 8 (64 bit)

Solution:

Don't forget to install other dependencies before installing ionic http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/installation.html

1) Uninstall Node from Control Panel

2) Restart PC

3) Download (MSI Installer) older version of Node from http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.38/ and for 64bit http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.38/x64/

4) Install Node version 0.10.38

5) npm install -g cordova

6) npm install -g ionic

Done!