# TSD error: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Tags: ssl, npm, tsd

I am following the [Angular 2 quick start guide](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html) and I'm stuck right at the beginning of it.

My company is filtering our network connections and modifying SSL negociation. In a man in the middle style they assign a self signed certificate as the CA of the destination's certificate.

Therefore when I execute the second command

```
npm install -g tsd
tsd query angular2 --action install
```

I get this:

```
stream.js:75
      throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
            ^
Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
    at Error (native)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:908:38)
    at emitNone (events.js:67:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:163:7)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:496:8)
```

Does anybody know a way of disabling the self signed certificate verification?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One little FYI first : if you just want to learn AngularJS, maybe it's not the best way to start with TypeScript. If it's the case for you, try the [tutorial on angularjs.org](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial), which use JavaScript and angular-seed.

Anyway, if you want to use tsd, you have to edit your tsdrc file (in your user's home directory), to set the proxy, and maybe, to turn of strictSSL. See https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/tsd#tsdrc

Following this documentation, this is what you certainly need to add to your tsdrc file :

```
{
    "proxy": "http://proxy.example.com:88",
    "strictSSL" : false
}
```

Edit : I also don't think it's an npm problem. So please update your question.

Comment: And if you have others problems, with npm this time, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559648/is-there-a-way-to-make-npm-install-the-command-to-work-behind-proxy

Comment: Hi nonox, thanks for your support. With the tsdrc file config it worked like a charm.

Comment: Great :) Now, you just have to change the title of the question from "NPM Error" to "TSD error". thx

Comment: Just mentioning in case someone faces similar problem like me. I was running into this error -->>> `error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@angular%2fcompiler: self signed certificate in certificate chain". `     So just added a .tsdrc file to my angular2-project and put in `{
    "strictSSL" : false
}` and then ran "yarn" and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

For **yarn** a very similar error occurs:

```
error An unexpected error occurred:
"https://registry.yarnpkg.com/generator-jhipster: self signed
certificate in certificate chain".
```

after

```
export NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0
```

I get:

```
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/generator-jhipster: SSL Error: SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN".
```

Finally **the solution**, with the below yarn is now happy to accept the man in the middle attack by my corporate proxy.

```
export NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0
yarn config set strict-ssl false --global
```

Comment: Thanks, this saved my day. 
I had the same issue to use "create-react-app", got the same error "SSL Error: SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN"..

Google brought me to this SO question and your "yarn config set strict-ssl false --global" saved my day.