# Install electron on ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, electron

When I try to install electron on Ubuntu 15.04 using

`sudo npm install electron-prebuilt -g`

This is what I get

```
/usr/local/bin/electron -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/electron-prebuilt/cli.js

> electron-prebuilt@0.28.3 postinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/electron-prebuilt
> node install.js

Downloading electron-v0.28.3-linux-x64.zip
Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=139936635598656:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:s23_clnt.c:795:


/usr/local/lib/node_modules/electron-prebuilt/install.js:15
  throw err
        ^
Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=139936635598656:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:s23_clnt.c:795:

npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node"
npm WARN For further explanations, please read
/usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian

npm ERR! electron-prebuilt@0.28.3 postinstall: `node install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 8
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the electron-prebuilt@0.28.3 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the electron-prebuilt package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node install.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls electron-prebuilt
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.19.0-18-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "electron-prebuilt"
npm ERR! cwd /usr/bin
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.21
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /usr/bin/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I tried

Creating a system link for node with the command:
`ln -s node nodejs` in the `/usr/bin/` folder

and

installing node-legacy package: `sudo apt-get install node-legacy`
as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559648/is-there-a-way-to-make-npm-install-the-command-to-work-behind-proxy)
with no luck.

Couldn't find anything more on other forums.So please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9):

Following steps worked for me:
(Assuming node and npm are already installed)

1. Updated the npm package to latest:-

   sudo npm install npm@latest -g
2. Installed electron with following switches:

   sudo npm install electron -g –-verbose --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root

Corrections/Suggestion from experienced people are always welcome. Hope it help to somebody.

Comment: The only answer that worked for me (having ELIFECYCLE errors). Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

**use:**

> ELECTRON_MIRROR=https://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/electron/ npm install

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you are behind a proxy.

You can disable it or make npm install work behind a proxy (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559648/is-there-a-way-to-make-npm-install-the-command-to-work-behind-proxy) question).

Comment: Yes, I'm indeed behind a proxy but I have already set all those config and other applications get installed just fine with npm.

Comment: Assuming you have fallowed the instructions in the mentioned post and it didn't work - are you able to disable this proxy? P.S. I've just installed electron-prebuild on a fresh copy of ubuntu just by installing node, npm and linking nodejs to node as you described. So I'm pretty sure it's still a proxy issue.

Comment: My network is provided by my institute through a proxy server.So I cannot disable it.I have to work out whatever it takes from behind the proxy itself.
Also do you think proxy affects different applications differently? because as I have mentioned,I tried performing installations of other modules and it worked with no errors or warnings

Comment: From your output it seems it still has issues with the ssl - it may be because electron-download is using it when downloading electron-prebuild. You can try to download electron from http mirror like so: set ELECTRON_MIRROR=http://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/electron/ && npm install electron-prebuild

Comment: `electron-prebuilt` also runs a script which fetches the binaries from aws. You may want to look at this: https://github.com/mafintosh/electron-prebuilt/issues/21

Answer (score 0):

You typed it wrong 
install nodejs-legacy

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy
```

to fix it and then continue installing electron

```
sudo npm install electron-prebuilt -g
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo npm install electron -g
```

This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

First install latest version of `node` and `npm` by

```
$ curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo bash -
$ sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

the latest `npm version` is now `6.9.0`, check the `npm version` with `npm --version`
if the `npm version` is `6.4.1` just first update `npm` by

```
$ npm install -g npm
```

If you have problem with permissions caused by `sudo` then you can `cd` into  `.npm-global`

```
$ cd /home/user_home_directory/.npm-global/
```

using `chmod` command to change permissions of all files and directories in this folder:

```
$ sudo chmod 777 * -R
```

After installation you must add this line to the end of `.bashrc` file:

```
export PATH="/home/user_home_directory/.npm-global/bin:$PATH"
```

After saving `.bashrc` just `source` it by

```
$ source .bashrc
```

After all done, you can install `electron` globally by

```
$ npm install -g electron
```

Answer (score 0):

I reached here because my final app wasn't installing on ubuntu.
In case someone has the same problem go to the build location and run from terminal using : 
`sudo dpkg -i <name of your install/build file>`
p.s. I didn't find this solution anywhere else which is why I'm posting it here

Answer (score 0):

Using this helps me:

```
sudo npm install electron -g  --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
```

without `--unsafe-perm=true --allow-root` I got error message like this:

```
> electron@10.1.5 postinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/electron
> node install.js

Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdtemp 
'/usr/local/lib/node_modules/electron/electron-download-rSlUcU'
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! electron@10.1.5 postinstall: `node install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the electron@10.1.5 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional 
logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-11-13T04_43_27_809Z-debug.log
```