# how to get around tunneling socket error with npm install?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, windows, npm

I am trying to run npm install in my angular project but results in an error:

```
error network tunneling socket could not be established, cause=read ECONNRESET
error network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
error network and is related to network connectivity.
error network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
```

I tried to set the npm proxy like this:

```
npm config set proxy http://myproxy
npm config set https-proxy https://myproxy
npm config set registry "http://registry.npmjs.org/"
```

What am I missing or how can I run npm install?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to make npm install (the command) to work behind proxy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559648/is-there-a-way-to-make-npm-install-the-command-to-work-behind-proxy)

Answer (score 4):

You should not use **'https'** but **'http'** as protocol when setting *"https-proxy"* in npm. Just do,

```
>npm config set https-proxy http://myproxy
```