# Error using npm on Windows shell on company proxy

Tags: windows, cordova, proxy, npm

I'm trying to install phonegap using

```
npm install -g phonegap
```

I'm on proxy so I set

```
npm config set proxy http://username:password@proxy.company.com:8080
npm config set https-proxy https://username:password@proxy.company.com:8080
```

The error I get when I try to install via `npm install  -g phonegap`

```
Assertion failed (wrap->ssl_) != (nullprt), file src\tls_wrap.cc, line 320
```

Comment: anyone??? it is strange that downloading another package from npm it does good...

Comment: changing the version of node to 0.8.28 it seems to connect but now the error is that seems to be missing package.json from folder \npm\node_modules\phonegap

Comment: Someone has opened an issue on the Node.js issue tracker regarding this assertion: [nodejs/node#2979](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/2979).

Comment: thank you! i will keep updated this post!!! :)

Comment: I'm seeing this in node 4.4.  What did you find out?

Comment: I solved reading this question, hope this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559648/is-there-a-way-to-make-npm-install-the-command-to-work-behind-proxy