# npm downloading phonegap multiple error

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm

i'm trying to download phonegap with npm from command line, i get always error with node version:4.0.0 and 4.1.0 specifically:
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32611474/error-using-npm-on-windows-shell-on-company-proxy)

i'm on company proxy and i can't change connection.
now changing version of node to: 0.10.0 i get those errors:

```
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, open 'C:\Documents and Settings\gcappella\node_modules\p
honegap\node_modules\prompt\node_modules\utile\node_modules\mkdirp\test\return_s
ync.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 5.1.2600
npm ERR! command "C:\\Programmi\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Programmi\\nodejs\\nod
e_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "phonegap"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Documents and Settings\gcappella
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.0
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.14
npm ERR! path C:\Documents and Settings\gcappella\node_modules\phonegap\node_mod
ules\prompt\node_modules\utile\node_modules\mkdirp\test\return_sync.js
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir 'C:\Documents and Settings\g
cappella\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\prompt\node_modules\utile\node_modul
es\i\test\inflector'
npm ERR! error rolling back  utile@0.2.1 { [Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir 'C:\Document
s and Settings\gcappella\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\prompt\node_modules\
utile\node_modules\i\test\inflector']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 53,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'ENOTEMPTY',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\gcappella\\node
_modules\\phonegap\\node_modules\\prompt\\node_modules\\utile\\node_modules\\i\\
test\\inflector' }
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir 'C:\Documents and Settings\g
cappella\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\prompt\node_modules\utile\node_modul
es\i\test\inflector'
npm ERR! error rolling back  prompt@0.2.11 { [Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir 'C:\Docume
nts and Settings\gcappella\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\prompt\node_module
s\utile\node_modules\i\test\inflector']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 53,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'ENOTEMPTY',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\gcappella\\node
_modules\\phonegap\\node_modules\\prompt\\node_modules\\utile\\node_modules\\i\\
test\\inflector' }
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir 'C:\Documents and Settings\g
cappella\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\prompt\node_modules\utile\node_modul
es\ncp\test'
npm ERR! error rolling back  ncp@0.4.2 { [Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir 'C:\Documents
and Settings\gcappella\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\prompt\node_modules\ut
ile\node_modules\ncp\test']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 53,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'ENOTEMPTY',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\gcappella\\node
_modules\\phonegap\\node_modules\\prompt\\node_modules\\utile\\node_modules\\ncp
\\test' }
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat 'C:\Documents and Settings\gcappella\node_modules\
phonegap\node_modules\prompt\node_modules\utile\node_modules\i\test\inflector\me
thods-test.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 5.1.2600
npm ERR! command "C:\\Programmi\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Programmi\\nodejs\\nod
e_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "phonegap"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Documents and Settings\gcappella
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.0
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.14
npm ERR! path C:\Documents and Settings\gcappella\node_modules\phonegap\node_mod
ules\prompt\node_modules\utile\node_modules\i\test\inflector\methods-test.js
npm ERR! fstream_path C:\Documents and Settings\gcappella\node_modules\phonegap\
node_modules\prompt\node_modules\utile\node_modules\i\test\inflector\methods-tes
t.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack C:\Programmi\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\fstream
\lib\writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:93:15)
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir 'C:\Documents and Settings\g
cappella\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\connect-phonegap\res\middleware\cord
ova'
npm ERR! error rolling back  phonegap@5.3.1+cordova.5.3.1 { [Error: ENOTEMPTY, r
mdir 'C:\Documents and Settings\gcappella\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\con
nect-phonegap\res\middleware\cordova']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 53,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'ENOTEMPTY',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\gcappella\\node
_modules\\phonegap\\node_modules\\connect-phonegap\\res\\middleware\\cordova' }
npm ERR! Error: No compatible version found: glob@'^5.0.14'
npm ERR! Valid install targets:
npm ERR! ["1.1.0","2.0.9","2.0.8","2.0.7","2.1.0","3.0.0","3.0.1","3.1.0","3.1.1
","3.1.2","3.1.3","3.1.4","3.1.5","3.1.6","3.1.7","3.1.9","3.1.10","3.1.11","3.1
.12","3.1.13","3.1.14","3.1.15","3.1.16","3.1.17","3.1.18","3.1.19","3.1.20","3.
1.21","3.2.0","3.2.1","3.2.3","3.2.4","3.2.5","3.2.6","3.2.7","3.2.8","3.2.9","3
.2.10","3.2.11","4.0.0","4.0.1","4.0.2","4.0.3","4.0.4","4.0.5","4.0.6","4.1.2-b
eta","4.1.2","4.1.3","4.1.4","4.1.5","4.1.6","4.2.0","4.2.1","4.2.2","4.3.0","4.
3.1","4.3.2","4.3.3","4.3.4","4.3.5","4.4.0","4.4.2","4.5.0","5.0.0","4.5.1","5.
0.1","4.5.2","5.0.2","4.5.3","5.0.3","5.0.4","5.0.5","5.0.6","5.0.7","5.0.9","5.
0.10","5.0.11","5.0.12","5.0.13","5.0.14"]
npm ERR!     at installTargetsError (C:\Programmi\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\ca
che.js:682:10)
npm ERR!     at C:\Programmi\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\cache.js:597:10
npm ERR!     at saved (C:\Programmi\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-reg
istry-client\lib\get.js:138:7)
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:93:15)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 5.1.2600
npm ERR! command "C:\\Programmi\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Programmi\\nodejs\\nod
e_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "phonegap"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Documents and Settings\gcappella
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.0
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.14
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/wordwrap
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/request
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/request
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/wordwrap
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/request/-/request-2.11.4.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/request/-/request-2.11.4.tgz
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/wordwrap/-/wordwrap-0.0.3.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/wordwrap/-/wordwrap-0.0.3.tgz
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/abbrev
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/abbrev
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/abbrev/-/abbrev-1.0.7.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/abbrev/-/abbrev-1.0.7.tgz
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/shelljs/0.3.0
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/semver
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-js/4.1.1
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/tar/1.0.2
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-registry-mapper
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/unorm/1.3.3
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-serve
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/valid-identifier/0.0.1
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/dep-graph/1.1.0
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/osenv/0.1.0
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/npm
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/xcode/0.8.0
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/elementtree/0.1.6
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/npmconf
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/request/2.47.0
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/init-package-json
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/properties-parser/0.2.3
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/rc/0.5.2
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/glob/4.0.6
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/plist/1.1.0
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/aliasify
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/bplist-parser/0.0.6
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-app-hello-world/3.9.0
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-registry-mapper
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/shelljs/0.3.0
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-js/4.1.1
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-registry-mapper/-/cordova-registr
y-mapper-1.1.11.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-serve
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/semver
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/tar/1.0.2
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-js/-/cordova-js-4.1.1.tgz
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/shelljs/-/shelljs-0.3.0.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/valid-identifier/0.0.1
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/dep-graph/1.1.0
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/tar/-/tar-1.0.2.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/unorm/1.3.3
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/npmconf
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/valid-identifier/-/valid-identifier-0.0.1
.tgz
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/dep-graph/-/dep-graph-1.1.0.tgz
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/unorm/-/unorm-1.3.3.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/osenv/0.1.0
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/request/2.47.0
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/xcode/0.8.0
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/init-package-json
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/osenv/-/osenv-0.1.0.tgz
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/request/-/request-2.47.0.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/elementtree/0.1.6
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/xcode/-/xcode-0.8.0.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/rc/0.5.2
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/npm
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/aliasify
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/plist/1.1.0
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/glob/4.0.6
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/properties-parser/0.2.3
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/elementtree/-/elementtree-0.1.6.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-registry-mapper/-/cordova-registr
y-mapper-1.1.11.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-js/-/cordova-js-4.1.1.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/tar/-/tar-1.0.2.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-app-hello-world/3.9.0
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/unorm/-/unorm-1.3.3.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/valid-identifier/-/valid-identifier-0.0.1
.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/dep-graph/-/dep-graph-1.1.0.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/osenv/-/osenv-0.1.0.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/xcode/-/xcode-0.8.0.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/request/-/request-2.47.0.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/elementtree/-/elementtree-0.1.6.tgz
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/properties-parser/-/properties-parser-0.2
.3.tgz
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/glob/-/glob-4.0.6.tgz
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/plist/-/plist-1.1.0.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/properties-parser/-/properties-parser-0.2
.3.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/plist/-/plist-1.1.0.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/glob/-/glob-4.0.6.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/shelljs/-/shelljs-0.3.0.tgz
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/rc/-/rc-0.5.2.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/rc/-/rc-0.5.2.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/bplist-parser/0.0.6
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-app-hello-world/-/cordova-app-hel
lo-world-3.9.0.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-app-hello-world/-/cordova-app-hel
lo-world-3.9.0.tgz
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/bplist-parser/-/bplist-parser-0.0.6.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/bplist-parser/-/bplist-parser-0.0.6.tgz
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Documents and Settings\gcappella\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

anyone can help a poor guy?

Answer (score 1):

are you sure this port `8080` is available ??

try to change port number, maybe it will help you bro...

Comment: no, infact i'm using 3128, 8080 is for example, thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

`npm@1.2.14` is extremely old and has not been supported for years. The crux of your issue is that such an old version of `npm` has no idea how to interpret the `^` semver operator you see here:

```
npm ERR! Error: No compatible version found: glob@'^5.0.14'
```

Hence an error is thrown. The solution is to simply upgrade. I would recommend upgrading both [Node.js](https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting#updating-node-on-windows) and [`npm`](https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting#upgrading-on-windows), since Node.js v0.10.0 is also very old and by using it you are subject to a handful of security vulnerabilities that have been fixed in the **years** since v0.10.0 was released.

Comment: ok if you click at the link i wrote in my question you will see that i've already  tried using node version:4.0.0 and 4.1.0, if you know why it gives me this error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32611474/error-using-npm-on-windows-shell-on-company-proxy
i'll be glad to use recent version of node and npm

Comment: I saw the link, but my answer is still valid as the reason why you are receiving the "no compatible version" error. The assertion error being thrown in your other question is coming from Node.js, not `npm`, specifically from [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v4.1.0/src/tls_wrap.cc#L320). I have not seen that before.