# How can I catalog npm requests when excuting npm install

Tags: node.js, npm, ionic-framework, sniffing

I'm working in an enviroment where I need to catalog all the npm http requests when executing `npm install .` for a specific ionic app.

It's necessary to open a specific set of urls in the proxy,  not only authenticate against it, enabling http_proxy and https_proxy environment variables, the proxy is only open for a specifis set of urls.

I have tell proxy mantainers that the urls for all npm GET's are: 
`https://registry.npmjs.org` , `http://registry.npmjs.org`, or `http://registry.npmjs.eu` ,

but it seems that only with those  urls the command does not work, maybe npm is calling another ones, so I need to catalogue them .

I'm trying to use a sniffer , in this case wireshark, filtering statistics with http.host, but the npm requests do not appear in the final report.

Is there a npm command, switch or parameter where can I see all the urls invoked in the command?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look [here](http://jjasonclark.com/how-to-setup-node-behind-web-proxy/) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559648/is-there-a-way-to-make-npm-install-the-command-to-work-behind-proxy)