# npm install doesn't work on Windows 10 even after setting proxy through npm config

Tags: node.js, windows, proxy, npm-install

I am getting the following error while doing **"npm install"** . I have already manually set the proxy. Can someone help me out on this

```
D:\nodejs>npm config set http_proxy <http_proxy>

D:\nodejs>npm config set https_proxy <https_proxy>

D:\nodejs>npm install
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv"D:\\nodejs\\node.exe""D:\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.4.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.8
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! syscall connect

npm ERR! network connect ETIMEDOUT 151.101.8.162:443
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\nodejs\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Check if my answer for more detailed setting will solve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559648/is-there-a-way-to-make-npm-install-the-command-to-work-behind-proxy/44758840#44758840

Answer (score 1):

This is not the issue with doing **npm config**.
try changing your organisation password and make sure it doesn't contain **'#'** in it.
run '**npm config**' with new password and you will be good to go.

Reason: I found out that symbols like  **'@'** get encoded automatically in **.npmrc** file(generated when you '**run npm**' config commands).
but for symbol **'#'** it is not getting encoded due to some reason and hence we get this error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to leave comments, but here is various solutions that may help:

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7781

I would start with making sure NPM is updated.