# Node Package install issue

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

Having trouble when trying to install any npm package, getting the error mentioned below.

[image]

Comment: if you are behind a proxy , please make sure that the proxy config is set properly !

Comment: I am not behind any proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is fixed when thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559648/is-there-a-way-to-make-npm-install-the-command-to-work-behind-proxy).

I Just added two steps ,

1. Setting strict ssl false

> npm config set strict-ssl false

2. And making registry pointing to npmjs registry.

> npm config set registry "http://registry.npmjs.org/"