# Getting following error while installing react native

Tags: react-native

ran the follwing command:

```
npm install -g react-native-cli
```

The error:

```
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 151.101.72.162:443
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1050:11)
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1073:20)
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1093:14)
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData  error for react-native-cli { Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 151.101.72.162:443
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1050:11)
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1073:20)
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1093:14)
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData   code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData   errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData   syscall: 'connect',
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData   address: '151.101.72.162',
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData   port: 443 }
```

I think the issue is mostly about proxy:
Also tried setting the proxy using command:

```
set HTTP_PROXY=http://your_proxy:your_port
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What error ? I can't guess

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to make npm install (the command) to work behind proxy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559648/is-there-a-way-to-make-npm-install-the-command-to-work-behind-proxy). Port 443 is SSL, so you need to `set HTTPS_PROXY` too.

Comment: I think i have added that answer in the question,But it didnt worked.@KenY-N

Comment: What is your npm version

Comment: `npm -v` prints `4.2.0`

Comment: Alright, this is more likely a issue with your network settings or proxy. Can you connect with some other network then try it

Comment: ran the following command :`npm set strict-ssl=false`.Done Issue Resolved.Thanks @TGMCians

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ran the following command :`npm set strict-ssl=false`