# npm install -g @angular/cli not working and hanging in windows 7

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli, npm-install

I am unable to install the angular cli from the npm and its getting stuck asking to loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree.

Steps taken:

C:\Windows\system32\node -v

v6.11.1

C:\Windows\system32\npm -v

3.10.10

C:\Windows\system32\npm install -g @angular/cli

Its gets stuck with the attached error

[image]

Comment: you probably already have an angular-cli `serve` running

Comment: Are you running this as an adminstrator?

Comment: I didn't notice any error on your screenshot, is it frozen on `loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree` step?

Comment: Are you running these commands from behind a proxy? If you are you could try [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559648/is-there-a-way-to-make-npm-install-the-command-to-work-behind-proxy)

Comment: @PierreDuc - Thanks for your comment. I am installing angular-cli for the first time. No angular-cli is running as I am unable to install it on the first place

Comment: @R.Richards - Thanks for your comment. Yes I am running it as an administrator. Shall I or Shall I not ?

Comment: @Haseoh - Thanks for your comment. Yes. Its now showing any error. It just gets stuck at this point and does not proceeds even after hours.

Comment: Running as admin is correct. This is a strange one! Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

I also stucked in the same problem. Below solution works for me.

It would be better if you upgrade your `node` and `npm` versions to latest. After that please follow the below steps to install the `angular/cli`:

Open your command prompt with administrative privileges and uninstall `angular/cli` by using `npm uninstall -g angular-cli` command.

Remove `node_modules` directory and then clear the cache by using `npm cache clear --force` command.

Remove `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm\` and `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache`.

Try to install the `angular/cli@latest` by using `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest` command.

Hope the above trick resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem for `npm@5.3.0` on `macOS`. It was resolved by checking my `package.json` file with [validator](http://package-json-validator.com).

In my case the problem was the git package version notation: `gulpjs/gulp.git#4.0` instead of `https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp.git#4.0`.

After changes I also regenerate `package-lock.json`.