# Unable to npm install Angular-cli after proxy configuration

Tags: node.js, angular, proxy, npm-install

I am trying to download Angular in Windows 10 using npm install. As I am on corporate proxy, I configured the proxy to username:password@server:port

However, I am facing this issue when running

`npm ERR! code E407
npm ERR! 407 Proxy Authorization Required: @angular/cli@latest`

The debug log as followed:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   '--proxy',
1 verbose cli   'http://XXXXX',     //Removed my proxy details
1 verbose cli   '--without-ssl',
1 verbose cli   '--insecure',
1 verbose cli   '-g',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   '@angular/cli' ]
2 info using npm@5.4.2
3 info using node@v8.8.1
4 verbose npm-session 40ab1dc3dabb6029
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readGlobalPackageData
7 http fetch GET 407 http://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli 109ms
8 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for @angular/cli@latest 407 Proxy Authorization Required: @angular/cli@latest
9 verbose stack Error: 407 Proxy Authorization Required: @angular/cli@latest
9 verbose stack     at fetch.then.res (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\fetchers\registry\fetch.js:42:19)
9 verbose stack     at tryCatcher (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
9 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:512:31)
9 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:569:18)
9 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
9 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromises (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:693:18)
9 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueue (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:133:16)
9 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueues (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:143:10)
9 verbose stack     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17:14)
9 verbose stack     at runCallback (timers.js:785:20)
9 verbose stack     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:747:5)
9 verbose stack     at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:718:5)
10 verbose cwd C:\Users\XXXXX
11 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.14393
12 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "--proxy" "http://XXXXX" "--without-ssl" "--insecure" "-g" "install" "@angular/cli"
13 verbose node v8.8.1
14 verbose npm  v5.4.2
15 error code E407
16 error 407 Proxy Authorization Required: @angular/cli@latest
17 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Any idea what could have cause the issue? Thanks!

Comment: use this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48224025/npm-behind-a-proxy-with-the-character-in-my-password/50214574#50214574).
it worked for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This configuration worked for me :

**method1 (command line):**

```
npm config set proxy http://user:password@domain_proxy:port/
npm config set https-proxy http://user:password@domain_proxy:port

be careful the url should be encoded. for example this password 01xx!tr should be introduced as 01xx%21tr. use this site to encode your url https://www.url-encode-decode.com/

example:
user/password => user1/01xx!tr
domain:port of the proxy => mydomain.org:8000
=> in that case :

npm config set proxy http://user1:01xx%21tr@mydomain.org:8000/
npm config set https-proxy http://user1:01xx%21tr@mydomain.org:8000
```

**method2 (edit node conifugration file):**

```
the method 2 is easier because we will not be botherd with encoding the urls

1- edit node configuration file (in windows it's located in %USERPROFILE%\.npmrc, example C:\Users\Jack\.npmrc)

2- add these lines
proxy=http://user:password@domain_proxy:port/
https-proxy=https-proxy http://user:passwor`enter code here`d@domain_proxy:port

example :
if the :
user/password => user1/01xx!tr
domain:port of the proxy => mydomain.org:8000

=> the configuration file should be look like this:

proxy=http://user1:01xx!tr@mydomain.org:8000/
https-proxy=http://user1:01xx!tr@mydomain.org:8000
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved it.
After I spent a bit of time on proxy issues, it turns out my mistake was setting 3 proxy variables: **proxy**, **http-proxy** and **https-proxy**.

(note: I read somewhere on stackoverflow that I was supposed to set *http-proxy* but this is wrong)

Removing **http-proxy** solved this for me.

Setting npm proxy and npm https_proxy is correct, as follows:

```
npm config set proxy http://user:password@proxy.companyname.com:port/
npm config set https-proxy http://user:password@proxy.companyname.com:port/
```

Comment: Thanks ,after two days of trying your answer worked finally.

Answer (score 0):

Try making the URL of npm registry to http instead of https. You can take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10304317/4226224).

Comment: Can you put the log file here of the error that is shown after you change it to http ?

Comment: [reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN .:80]

Indicates that there is a DNS resolution issue. Please check the proxy & port of your corporate proxy configuration. Many uses 8080 as port of proxy.

Comment: Have changed the port to 8080, the error i have gotten is the same as what I have previously. Thank you

Comment: Basically you need to check the proxy port configured for your corporate network. 8080 might not be the port of your corporate proxy. Any how, this is a DNS resolution issue of npm.

Answer (score 0):

If you have configured Proxy and Still you are not able to install using npm command. You can try below command. It seemed you need to clear some stuff - and that will fix the issue.

```
npm cache verify
```

Answer (score 0):

This steps worked for me

Edit `.npmrc` file 
add below lines

```
proxy=http://username:password@proxyaddress:portno
https-proxy=http://username:password@proxyaddress:portno
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing that worked for me as below,
Issue: Registry defined at "C:\Users*user-name*.npmrc" was wrong. Need to update npm config registry.

Step 1
Solution: Removed registry entry from "C:\Users*user-name*.npmrc" file.

Step 2
After Step 1 I got below error

> npm install -g @angular/cli
>   npm WARN registry Unexpected warning for https://registry.npmjs.org/: Miscellaneous Warning SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli failed, reason: self signed certificate in certificate chain
>   npm WARN registry Using stale package data from https://registry.npmjs.org/ due to a request error during revalidation.

Issue: The npm maintainers announced on February 27th that npm’s Self-Signed Certificate is No More:
A bunch of users received a “SELFSIGNEDCERTINCHAIN” error during installing and publishing packages throughout the day today. npm no longer supports its self-signed certificates.
However, the recommended fix failed for me.

Solution: Open command prompt, and run below commands.
SETLOCAL
SET npm_config_strict-ssl=false
npm install npm -g --ca=null
npm --version
ENDLOCAL

Step 3 
Now >npm install -g @angular/cli running all ok.

Answer (score 0):

To config proxy in office,

```
npm config set proxy http://user:password@proxy.companyname.com:port/
npm config set https-proxy http://user:password@proxy.companyname.com:port/
```