# unable to install electron on high sierra

Tags: node.js, npm, electron, npm-install

I have been trying to install electron using npm on high sierra and I am unable to do so, sudo or changing folder permission, nothing seems to work.

I did see this error on several posts but most of them point to using the correct node version. Some links I checked: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47885108/unable-to-install-electron-from-npm) [2](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start/issues/179)

I was on version 9.2.1 but switched to version 8.2.1 based on what I saw in [electron](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/.node-version).

Below is the screenshot of the error:
[image]

Is this because for some reason I am forbidden from adding certain files to my root? I have tis doubt because of late I am having a lot of hassle installing any software. Is there a way to get rid of this problem for good?

Comment: Why would you want to install Electron globally? Installing as a dev dependency to a local project is recommended by the authors

Comment: @PatrickHund I tried doing that initially, got the same error. I was trying this command: npm install electron --save-dev --save-exact and saw the same error.

Comment: I checked the same problem [here](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17268). But that solution does not work for me

Comment: Did you follow these instructions? https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/installation.md#troubleshooting

Comment: Omg yes this did it! I did not achieve this in 1 step though:

Comment: Step 1: npm install --platform=linux electron . This gave an error (SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.) I was familiar with a hack to resolve this error. Step 2: nvm install node --reinstall-packages-from=node. Step 3: npm install --platform=linux electron. Thats it. Thanks a lot @PatrickHund

Comment: Okay for those facing a problem with installation using npm, I found a way to install using homebrew - works like a charm! Link is : 
    http://macappstore.org/electron/

Answer (score 0):

I had faced same problem, the reason behind is the installer you use to install your node either brew or nvm doesn't has root access privileges.

brew :- By default brew doen't have root access permission to install applications.

nvm :-  same case for nvm, Installed Node doen't have root access permission to install libs.

First option, Install nodejs manually by downloading from [server](https://nodejs.org/en/), install it and then try to install electron by using following command

```
npm install electron --save-dev
```

or

```
sudo npm install electron --save-dev
```

Second option, give the nvm or brew root privileges