# Failed to create app with create-react-app in Linux 16.04

Tags: javascript, linux, reactjs

I am trying to create new app with create-react-app.
Below is the error.
Please help. Thanks in advance

```
➜ REACT create-react-app my-app

Creating a new React app in /media/budi/Tjung/#TJUNG/REACT/my-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

yarn add v1.6.0
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
error An unexpected error occurred: "http://registry.npmjs.org/react: > ETIMEDOUT".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/media/budi/Tjung/#TJUNG/REACT/my-app/yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.

Aborting installation.
  yarnpkg add --exact react react-dom react-scripts --cwd /media/budi/Tjung/#TJUNG/REACT/my-app has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting generated file... yarn-error.log
Deleting my-app / from /media/budi/Tjung/#TJUNG/REACT
Done.
```

[error image at CLI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPdPR.png)

Comment: Try `npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/` and see if that works.

Comment: look at https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/576

Comment: @Colin ... I have tried it and also try this `npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/` ,  its output same error.

Comment: @SantoshSharma ... I have npm and yarn installed with the latest version. when i type `create-react-app <app-name>` , its automatically use yarn to create new app. I have tried remove my yarn, create react app with npm, takes long time (30 minutes) still not finish created.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like network problem to me. You could be behind a proxy. If that is the case, configure your proxy in npm like this

```
npm config set proxy http://proxy_host:port
```

For `https`

```
npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
```

**Note**: The https-proxy doesn't have https as the protocol, but http.

Optionally you can also try,

```
npm config set strict-ssl false
```

Checkout this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13138231/3513336)

Answer (score 0):

check if npm exists on your system.

try the commands in this order.

`1. npm install --save create-react-app
2. create-react-app projectname`

The name of the project must be in lowercase

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have Node installed, you can use npm to install the create-react-native-app command line utility:

```
npm install -g create-react-native-app
```

Then run the following commands to create a new React Native project called "my-app":

```
create-react-native-app my-app

cd my-app
npm start
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solve this problem.. it is about internet speed connection. 
.
When I met this problem, I have spent one day to find out the solution. I read so many article about ETIMEDOUT. I had uninstall and re-install npm and yarn. Still doesn't solve my problem. 
.
Until then I found the spot that has high speed internet connection. Fortunately I can create new app with create-react-app.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are problem with your configurations of npm package.

Maybe somewhere, you set up some proxy configuration to npm variables.

You can reset configs running this script in terminal

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "" > $(npm config get globalconfig)'
```

and wait until process will end and run

```
exit
```

Open another terminal window and try