# How to configure .pac file for proxy script in node.js + pac-resolver

Tags: node.js

I am not able to install any module using npm command. I have below result when When i run `npm config list` command i get below output.

```
https-proxy = "http://host.name.changed:80/"
proxy = "http://host.name.changed:80/"
registry = "http://registry.npmjs.org/"
```

The proxy configured in my internet explorer is having proxy.pac file as below without any port.

http://host.name.changed/proxy.pac

if https://www.npmjs.com/package/pac-resolver/v/3.0.0 is the answer, how do I Install pac-resolver even npm install pac-resolver does not work !!

Answer (score 0):

First, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559648/is-there-a-way-to-make-npm-install-the-command-to-work-behind-proxy) and answer for configuring npm's proxy. The pac-resolver package would just allow you to see which proxy the pac file is resolving to when requesting a page from some host, so there is no need to use it in order to utilize npm.

Second, most command line tools like npm are not configured to use IE's proxy settings so in most cases you'll have to configure this in a file somewhere. `.npmrc` in npm's case.

Also checkout [cntlm](http://cntlm.sourceforge.net) which can simplify proxy configuration for your system.