# How to install files using npm behind proxy?

Tags: npm, npm-install

While running the `npm install` command, I'm getting:

> ERR 418 I m a teapot

I set a proxy but I'm not sure whether it is correctly parsed. I doubt that the proxy might be the reason. Can someone help me on this? I also ran `npm config get proxy`.

Comment: I ran npm config get proxy Getting output as http://DomainName/username:password@ProxyURL.com:port/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to make npm install (the command) to work behind proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559648/is-there-a-way-to-make-npm-install-the-command-to-work-behind-proxy)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
npm config set proxy 213.169.158.34:8080
npm config set https-proxy 213.169.158.34:443
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
npm instal
```