# Request to http://registry.npmjs.org/check failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED

Tags: node.js, npm

When I run this commend "npm install -g check" on cmd I have the following error

```
npm ERR! code ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! errno ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! FetchError: request to http://registry.npmjs.org/check failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 10.141.0.60:80
```

**using:**

- OS: Windows 10
- Node Version: v8.10.0
- npm version: 5.6.0
- Domain (AD): kmsd
- User: mu789
- Proxy: 10.40.140.60:4000

I tried following commends, but still have the same issue

```
npm set strict-ssl=false
npm config set registry "http://registry.npmjs.org/"
npm config set proxy  http://kmsd\mu789:ab_132@10.40.140.60:4000/ 
npm config set https-proxy http://kmsd\mu789:ab_132@10.40.140.60:4000/
```

--

```
npm config set proxy  http://kmsd%5Cmu789:ab_132@10.40.140.60:4000/ 
npm config set https-proxy http://kmsd%5Cmu789:ab_132@10.40.140.60:4000/
```

--

```
npm config set proxy http://mu789:ab_132@10.40.140.60:4000/ 
npm config set https-proxy http://mu789:ab_132@10.40.140.60:4000/
```

--

.npmrc

```
proxy=http://kmsd\mu789:ab_132@10.40.140.60:4000/ 
https-proxy=http://kmsd\mu789:ab_132@10.40.140.60:4000/
```

--

.npmrc

```
proxy=http://"kmsd\mu789:ab_132"@10.40.140.60:4000
https-proxy=http://"kmsd\mu789:ab_132"@10.40.140.60:4000
```

--

.npmrc

```
proxy="http://kmsd\mu789:ab_132@10.40.140.60:4000/"
https-proxy="http://kmsd\mu789:ab_132@10.40.140.60:4000/"
```

I tried all methods in [Is there a way to make npm install (the command) to work behind proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559648/is-there-a-way-to-make-npm-install-the-command-to-work-behind-proxy) but still have the issue.

Answer (score 1):

format for proxy "http://mu789:kmsd@10.40.140.60:4000" which should be put in .npmrc file.
Please try this and check if you still face this isue.
Assuming kmsd is password for the corp

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, was able to successfully install it outside my company's corporate network or try adding the proxy to proxy bypass list. Hope it helps!