# Install tensorflow.js using npm is not working

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I'm new to TensorFlow.js and just started to follow the tutorial from https://js.tensorflow.org/. I tried to install @tensorflow/tfjs via npm but it doesn't work. Here is the error message I've got:

```
XXXXXXX$ npm install @tensorflow/tfjs
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: @tensorflow/tfjs-converter@0.5.7
```

But if I try to install it again, the error message changed:

```
XXXXXXX$ npm install @tensorflow/tfjs
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: @tensorflow/tfjs-core@0.12.11
```

According to https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tensorflow/tfjs, TensorFlow.js Core & TensorFlow.js Converter should come with TensorFlow.js and I don't need to do any extra installation. Could anyone plz let me know what could be the problem? I tried to run `npm install @tensorflow/tfjs@0.XX.X` and `npm install @tensorflow/tfjs --save` but none of them work.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue related not to tensorflowJs but to the proxy that you are using in your local network.
You can try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559648/is-there-a-way-to-make-npm-install-the-command-to-work-behind-proxy) to make npm work behind a proxy.

Comment: Thanks you were right, the issue was about node and npm not the tensorflowJs

Answer (score 0):

Figured out what went wrong, I have 2 different versions of Node.js (one is `8.X.X` the other `10.X.X`) and they were fighting each other. Tried to update or reinstall via HomeBrew, finally switched Node.js to `10.X.X` but my npm version was `5.6.X` which didn't support Node 10. Eventually uninstalled npm and node, downloaded the the package from `https://nodejs.org/` and installed, run the `npm install @tensorflow/tfjs` again and everything worked.