# How to configure npm proxy for the company's Zscaler settings?

Tags: npm, zscaler

0

In my company I can't download the node modules via npm, because the connection is being refused. We use a Zscaler with a .pac config file. I tried to configure the proxy via various tutorials

[Is there a way to make npm install (the command) to work behind proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559648/is-there-a-way-to-make-npm-install-the-command-to-work-behind-proxy)

https://www.jhipster.tech/configuring-a-corporate-proxy/

but I don't get it to work. When I type

```
npm --proxy http://username:password@cacheaddress.com.br:80 install packagename
```

it tells me "event not found", when I type the password. If I leave the password field empty, I get

```
npm ERR! 418 I'm a teapot - GET http://registry.npmjs.org/electron - got unknown host (registry.npmjs.org:80)
```

Comment: What Operating System are you using and is this still an issue (aware quite an old thread) but I have this working in our setup so happy to help if others need it.

Comment: I don’t work there anymore unfortunately