# yarn 'There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...'

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, yarnpkg

I'm working behind my institute proxy  and can't use yarn, its showing

```
yarn install v1.16.0
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
```

npm install giving me this error

```
network tunneling socket could not be established, statusCode=503
```

Yarn version 1.16.0;  node version 8.10.0; npm version 3.5.2; ubuntu 18.04.02

**What I have done so far:**

1. set proxy in `/etc/apt/apt.conf` and `/etc/environment`

   Acquire::http::proxy "http://username:password@proxy:port";
   Acquire::https::proxy "http://username:password@proxy:port";
   Acquire::ftp::proxy "http://username:password@proxy:port";
2. set proxy in `.bashrc`

   export http_proxy="http://username:password@proxy:port";
   export https_proxy="http://username:password@proxy:port";
   export HTTPS_PROXY="http://username:password@proxy:port"
   export HTTP_PROXY="http://username:password@proxy:port"
3. `yarn install --network-timeout 100000`
4. yarn config set proxy http://username:password@host:port
   yarn config set https-proxy http://username:password@host:port
5. with npm

   npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
   npm config set proxy http://username:mypassword@proxy:port
   npm config set https-proxy http://username:mypassword@proxy:port
   npm config set strict-ssl false
   npm --proxy http://myusername:mypassword@proxy.us.somecompany:8080 --without-ssl --insecure -g install
6. Did all of these mentioned here https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/5259#issuecomment-379769451
7. Did all these [Is there a way to make npm install (the command) to work behind proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559648/is-there-a-way-to-make-npm-install-the-command-to-work-behind-proxy)

None of them fixed the problem. How do I make yarn work in this case?

UPDATE:
I have tried :
$ wget https://registry.npmjs.org/requests/-/requests-0.2.2.tgz
--2019-06-07 14:15:45--  https://registry.npmjs.org/requests/-/requests-0.2.2.tgz
Resolving proxy.iacs.res.in (proxy.iacs.res.in)... 192.168.1.106, 192.168.1.237
Connecting to proxy.iacs.res.in (proxy.iacs.res.in)|192.168.1.106|:3128... connected.
Proxy tunneling failed: Service UnavailableUnable to establish SSL connection.

Comment: You have a http proxy, not a https proxy with insecure certificates, then don't use "strict-ssl false" or "insecure" proxy because it does not make sense