# Npm Error: 503 Service Unavailable for npm install command

Tags: node.js, npm

Im trying to run npm install command but i got this error Error: 503 Service Unavailable for npm install command, Can any one please im requesting you to solve this one.

This is actual complete error im getting on error log file

```
3413 verbose stack Error: 503 Service Unavailable - GET http://52.169.74.37:8081/repository/npm-private/@ctc%2fctc-pubsub-common
3413 verbose stack     at res.buffer.catch.then.body (C:\node\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-fetch\check-response.js:104:15)
3413 verbose stack     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
3414 verbose statusCode 503
3415 verbose pkgid @ctc/ctc-pubsub-common@^1.0.5
3416 verbose cwd C:\Users\vktest\pro
3417 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.15063
3418 verbose argv "C:\\node\\node.exe" "C:\\node\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
3419 verbose node v10.16.3
3420 verbose npm  v6.9.0
3421 error code E503
3422 error 503 Service Unavailable - GET http://52.169.74.37:8081/repository/npm-private/@ctc%2fctc-pubsub-common
3423 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Seems like your npm registry config pointing to some private registry that is down or unavailable.

Try to check npm configuration :

```
npm config get registry
```

It should be like :

```
 http://52.169.74.37:8081
```

So update the config which will point to offical registry.

```
 npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.com/
```

Comment: No @Adil its still showing same error even after i tried  npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.com/ this its showing same error

Comment: Are you behind proxy?

Comment: Yes im behind proxy using proxy.companyname.com with 8080 port

Comment: Then it will not work, try with out proxy or configure accordingly to the proxy

Comment: follow these steps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559648/is-there-a-way-to-make-npm-install-the-command-to-work-behind-proxy

Comment: Yes I have configured proxy according to my proxy settings but still I'm facing same issue

Comment: may be issue with proxy, but this common issue behind proxy

Comment: How can I set proxy I tried with this commands.  npm config set proxy http://domainid:domainpassword@domainip:domainport also for https_proxy   and npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org.

Comment: I think the problem is with .npmrc file under project. What this file does. When I run npm I sqlite3 it's shown one ipnumber with port with registry which is available on .npmrc file same one

Comment: @Adil Thank you for your time. Finally it's working

Comment: For me this url worked `https://registry.npmjs.org/`

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes (but it's rare) it's because the npm services are down. You can check npm services status on their website : [status.npmjs.org](https://status.npmjs.org/)

Comment: Was just down.  Back up pretty quick though.  That was the issue for me.  Useful link.

Answer (score 5):

You may try to set these parameters:

```
npm config set proxy "http://proxy.url:port/"
npm config set https-proxy "http://proxy.url:port/"
npm config set strict-ssl false
npm config set registry "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a good explanation of issue and solution

[NPM Error "failed to fetch from registry" when Installing Module](https://stackabuse.com/npm-error-failed-to-fetch-from-registry-when-installing-module/)

**Old/Buggy NPM Version**

As you might have noticed from the error message above, the npm version being used is pretty old. In this example we were using Node v0.6.10 and npm v1.1.0-3. This version is known to have some problems with Ubuntu 12.04, so your best bet is to update Node (and npm along with it) to the newest version:

```
$ sudo npm update npm -g
```

If you want to re-install completely, you'll first want to completely remove the current Node/npm executables:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge nodejs npm
```

Then re-install using a more updated version, like from Nodesource:

```
$ curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | sudo bash -
$ sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Or, even better, you can check out this article for a more thorough guide to installing Node.js on Ubuntu.

**Can't Download Over HTTPS**

For one reason or another, some people can't connect to the registry via HTTPS. This can be fixed by setting the registry to use HTTP instead:

```
$ npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
$ npm config set strict-ssl false
```

This isn't recommended, however, since your packages will then be downloaded insecurely. It would be best to find the actual root cause instead of using a work-around like this.

**Corporate Proxy**

For many people, the root cause is actually because a proxy is being used on their network. If this is the case, you can use the following commands to set the HTTP and HTTPS proxies:

```
$ npm config set proxy http://user:password@proxy.example.com:8181
$ npm config set https-proxy http://user:password@proxy.example.com:8181
```

This will save the new configurations and should allow you to access the internet with npm.

Answer (score 0):

try using local npm looks like service not available in your country
https://www.npmjs.com/package/local-npm

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, In my case, it worked.

```
npm --registry http://registry.npmjs.eu/ install karma
```

Comment: No its not working @Ankit kumar i tried npm --registry http://registry.npmjs.eu/ install karma but still showing same error

Answer (score 0):

I have a same problem with the publish.

first, I remove `proxy` and `https-proxy` config with this command:

```
npm config delete proxy
npm config delete https-proxy
```

then I publish my package with this command:

```
npm publish
```

I hope is useful.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the `NO_PROXY` variable was missing, but `HTTP_PROXY` was set. NPM tried to go over the proxy, which was wrong in my case.

I declared the npm config variable `noproxy` (without underscore)

```
npm set noproxy "localhost,.mydomain.de"
```

Alternately one can set the environment variable NO_PROXY (with underscore)

```
SET NO_PROXY=localhost,.mydomain.de
```

ATTENTION: npm doesn't understand "*" (`*.mydomain.de` would be wrong) and multiple servers must be separated by "," (not semicolon).

*Tested with Windows 10 and nodejs16 (npm 8.19.2) und nodejs19 (npm 8.19.3)*

Answer (score -12):

You can try typing this;

*npm install*

Comment: OP is saying `Im trying to run npm install command but i got this error` and your answer is to do `npm install`. Isn't this exactly what OP already did?

Comment: yes, I solved it by trying it. you try too