# E503 Error found when publishing NPM. How could i fix it?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

I got this error when I tried to run npm publish on my project.

`npm ERR! code E503`

`npm ERR! 503 Service Unavailable - PUT https://registry.npmjs.org/sakibb/sakibbb - Service Unavailable`

**NB: I already followed this instruction video but still got the same result:**

[Instruction video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rTsz09zRuTU)

Comment: What instruction did you follow? Looks like you forgot to include that information in your question. A 503 error sounds like there was an issue with npm, but looking at https://status.npmjs.org/ shows there have been no issues today - have you tried publishing again recently? Are you still getting this error?

Comment: @cdimitroulas yes, still I'm getting an error from that. i have attached the instruction video, which actually I was following.

Comment: Are you using a proxy? Some of the answers here helped someone who was behind a proxy to connect to npm successfully https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57923831/npm-error-503-service-unavailable-for-npm-install-command