# issues running npm/npm to create a react app

Tags: node.js, npm

Hi guys im fairly new to coding, im having trouble with node npm, specifically creating a react app.
When i run npm init, it works but not npm/npx creat-react-app. i have even tried just running create-react-app just to see if it might work.
I have installed nodejs and pasted the path in my environment variables. i have tried npm, npx but no luck.

The error im getting is "npm ERR! code ERR_OSSL_PEM_NO_START_LINE"
                        "npm ERR! error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line"
What could the issue be? 
Its the first time i come across this issue.

Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
npm set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

and again

```
npx creat-react-app my-app
```

Comment: it starts off perfectly but then it kicks out an error: error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.npmjs.org/react: error0909006C:PEM routing:get_name:no startline"
and then everything is deleted again.

Comment: npm -v is 6.12.1
node -v is 12.13.1

Comment: I think you are behind proxy. Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18346387/6170527) about proxy config