# npm install does not seem to work in my case

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I downloaded node.js and when I run CLI command `npm install -g @angular/cli` I get these errors:

```
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to http://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND proxy.example.com
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Omar Abdelkefi\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-03-08T13_10_01_192Z-debug.log
```

Please any help

Comment: maybe you have to set the proxy settings. It is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559648/is-there-a-way-to-make-npm-install-the-command-to-work-behind-proxy

Answer (score 0):

If there is a such error ...

> npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly

then you have to set the proxy properly

```
$ npm config set proxy http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX
```

plus

```
$ npm config set https-proxy http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX
```

You can check the current proxy via :

```
$ npm config get proxy
```

If there is a need to delete proxy , then go ahead and do : (**Try below first**)

```
$ npm config rm proxy   
$ npm config rm https-proxy
```