# Proxy error in cmd - node package manager

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, http-proxy

I'm having the following proxy error when i execute the install cmd : 
npm install -g @angular/cli@8.0.0

```
Request to https://registry.npmjs.org/typescript failed, reason : connect ETIMEDOUT
This is a problem related to network connectivity.
In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings
If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this solution here. You should be able to add a proxy for npm modules instead of angular as separate.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10304317/10179262

Comment: That seems like a security bug, you are using a VPN or Proxy?
Link of solution: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17947#issuecomment-337180591

Comment: Yes I'm using remote access (VPN). @RodrigoAlcorta

Comment: I guess that will block your npm system by security policies, can you try again but without VPN?

Comment: Actually I'm accessing a system remotely using VPN so how can i resolve this issue without disabling my fortiClient VPN access. @RodrigoAlcorta

Comment: What's yout OS? Because perhaps you need to edit some file @deepdalvi

Comment: @RodrigoAlcorta Thanks for the follow up. The issue was with the internal network where i was accessing the remote system.