# couldn't run npm ci

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-ci

node.js - v12.16.2

npm - 6.14.4

OS - windows 10

When I run `npm ci` i get error.

The complete error log:

```
npm WARN prepare removing existing node_modules/ before installation

> fsevents@1.2.4 install G:\Agrima\workspace\VoTT\node_modules\fsevents
> node install


> node-sass@4.11.0 install G:\Agrima\workspace\VoTT\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.11.0/win32-x64-72_binding.node Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.11.0/win32-x64-72_binding.node":

HTTP error 404 Not Found

Hint: If github.com is not accessible in your location
      try setting a proxy via HTTP_PROXY, e.g.

      export HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:1234

or configure npm proxy via

      npm config set proxy http://example.com:8080

> node-sass@4.11.0 postinstall G:\Agrima\workspace\VoTT\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe G:\Agrima\workspace\VoTT\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild
--verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library= gyp info it worked if it ends with ok gyp verb cli [ gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe', gyp verb cli   'G:\\Agrima\\workspace\\VoTT\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js', gyp verb cli   'rebuild', gyp verb cli   '--verbose', gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=', gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=', gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=', gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library=' gyp verb cli ] gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0 gyp info using node@12.16.2 | win32 | x64 gyp verb command rebuild [] gyp verb command clean [] gyp verb clean removing "build" directory gyp verb command configure [] gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2 gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (G:\Agrima\workspace\VoTT\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12) gyp verb `which` failed     at F (G:\Agrima\workspace\VoTT\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19) gyp verb `which` failed     at E (G:\Agrima\workspace\VoTT\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29) gyp verb `which` failed     at G:\Agrima\workspace\VoTT\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16 gyp verb `which` failed     at G:\Agrima\workspace\VoTT\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5 gyp verb `which` failed     at G:\Agrima\workspace\VoTT\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5 gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:167:21) gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2 gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (G:\Agrima\workspace\VoTT\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12) gyp verb `which` failed     at F (G:\Agrima\workspace\VoTT\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19) gyp verb `which` failed     at E (G:\Agrima\workspace\VoTT\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29) gyp verb `which` failed     at G:\Agrima\workspace\VoTT\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16 gyp verb `which` failed     at G:\Agrima\workspace\VoTT\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5 gyp verb `which` failed     at G:\Agrima\workspace\VoTT\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5 gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:167:21) { gyp verb `which` failed   stack: 'Error: not found: python2\n' + gyp verb `which` failed     '    at getNotFoundError (G:\\Agrima\\workspace\\VoTT\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:13:12)\n'
+ gyp verb `which` failed     '    at F (G:\\Agrima\\workspace\\VoTT\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:68:19)\n'
+ gyp verb `which` failed     '    at E (G:\\Agrima\\workspace\\VoTT\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:80:29)\n'
+ gyp verb `which` failed     '    at G:\\Agrima\\workspace\\VoTT\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:89:16\n' + gyp verb `which` failed     '    at G:\\Agrima\\workspace\\VoTT\\node_modules\\isexe\\index.js:42:5\n' + gyp verb `which` failed     '    at G:\\Agrima\\workspace\\VoTT\\node_modules\\isexe\\windows.js:36:5\n' + gyp verb `which` failed     '    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:167:21)', gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT' gyp verb `which` failed } gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH gyp verb `which` succeeded python C:\Program Files\Python36\python.EXE gyp ERR! configure error gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Program Files\Python36\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3]; gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1 gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3]; gyp ERR! stack                                ^ gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax gyp ERR! stack gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:303:12) gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:310:20) gyp ERR! stack  at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16) gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5) gyp ERR! System Windows_NT
10.0.17134 gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "G:\\Agrima\\workspace\\VoTT\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library=" gyp ERR! cwd G:\Agrima\workspace\VoTT\node_modules\node-sass gyp ERR! node -v v12.16.2 gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0 gyp ERR! not ok Build failed with error code: 1 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! node-sass@4.11.0 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.11.0 postinstall script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!     C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-23T05_50_10_745Z-debug.log
```

Tried to do **npm install**, etc which was found in other sources, But failed each time.

Comment: it seems you are behind the proxy. Github is not reachable from your network

Comment: Is there any solution to it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559648/is-there-a-way-to-make-npm-install-the-command-to-work-behind-proxy