# Proxy error any package have not downloaded?

Tags: proxy, ionic3

I am following these three commands, but it still resulted in an error.

```
#npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
#npm config set http_proxy=http://domain:8080
```

After these command before ran two commands.

````
#npm config set proxy http://domain:8080
#npm rebuild node-sass
#npm install
#ionic serve

Error:
```none
Admins-Mac-mini-5:~ techwinlabs$ sudo npm install -g cordova ionic
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to http://registry.npmjs.org/cordova failed, 
reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND proxy.company.com proxy.company.com:8080
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network 
settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/techwinlabs/.npm/_logs/2020-07-15T08_06_22_790Z-debug.log
````

Comment: for http its `set proxy` not `set http_proxy`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to make npm install (the command) to work behind proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559648/is-there-a-way-to-make-npm-install-the-command-to-work-behind-proxy)

Comment: @Krzysztof Krzeszewski Thanks for Answer but in this Link there is alot answers so plz tell me which will have best for this problem

Comment: @Krzysztof Krzeszewski when i did change set http_proxy to set proxy and ran it but still this problem is not fixed give me same error

Comment: what proxy are you using? I'm asking because `proxy.company.com` is not a real url, just a sample you probably found somewhere, i'm just wondering whether you realize this and are trying to hide the actual url, or are you just unaware of it

Comment: sometime some companies have a private repository (NEXUS, JFROG ..) used like a mirror, for access to external servers.

Comment: @Krzysztof Krzeszewski  check it please https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-6-PNdN9bPMQ/Xw7S9k7rVlI/AAAAAAAABfk/yIm2mn7l9EIYcxkmoVBBy6TX5MJqSaXaQCK8BGAsYHg/s0/2020-07-15.png

Comment: @SandeepAmbedkar "so plz tell me which will have best for this problem" that is for you to figure out. Krzysztof brought you to the water, drinking it is your job.

Comment: Finally issue is fixed with running these three command
*****************************************************************************
# npm config set http-proxy null

# npm config set https-proxy null

# npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/

**************************************************

Proxy will have null for http and https…
***Thankyou to all for cooperation***

Comment: Pranav Hosangadi actually i am working on ionic3 basically it is my job currenty but which link did  provided by @Krzysztof Krzeszewski to me that link has variouse puzzle but will much helpfull for other issue command so this problem i did solve by me with R&D