# How to setup .npmrc file on linux Redhat server

Tags: node.js, npm

I have downloaded node-v12.4.0-linux-x64.tar.gz from internal repository (I cannot download/install anything from outside my internal repo) and set up $PATH. Now node -v showing v12.4.0 and npm -v showing 6.9.0. on the server

But I am not finding how to setup .npmrc file that I need for configuring my repository like I did on windows. Can someone let me know how I can setup .npmrc on Linux server?

Comment: Are you behind any proxy server?

Comment: @kiranvj yes I am.

Comment: Did you try these steps https://stackoverflow.com/a/10304317/1188322