# Angular-13 new project consistently failed to install on my Windows-10

Tags: angular, npm

For some days now I have been trying to install Angular-13 on my windows-10 without any success:

ng --version

gives me:

```
Angular CLI: 13.3.0
Node: 16.14.2
Package Manager: npm 8.5.0
OS: win32 x64

Angular: undefined
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.1303.0 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/core         13.3.0 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics   13.3.0 (cli-only)
@schematics/angular          13.3.0 (cli-only)
```

but when I did ng new my-project, I got this error:

```
npm ERR! code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! errno ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! network Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/cacache: Socket timeout
```

then I did:

```
npm cache clean --force
npm config set fetch-retry-mintimeout 20000
npm config set fetch-retry-maxtimeout 120000
```

> npm install

the error changed to:

```
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
```

Just moving from one error to the other.

Proxy is not setup:

[image: proxy]

How do I completely resolve all errors, ang Angular project installed?

Thanks

Comment: Clear npm cache and try again "npm  cache clear --force"

Comment: Can you able to open https://registry.npmjs.org/ in your browser?

Comment: Yes @rohithpoya - I got this:   {"db_name":"registry","engine":"couch_bt_engine","doc_count":2740346,"doc_del_count":334,"update_seq":16038752,"purge_seq":0,"compact_running":false,"sizes":{"active":50288079602,"external":161731056984,"file":50400137456},"disk_size":50400137456,"data_size":50288079602,"other":{"data_size":161731056984},"instance_start_time":"1647647021618067","disk_format_version":7,"committed_update_seq":16038752,"compacted_seq":16038242,"uuid":"964c127ddcbbd59982db896a0f9e8a99"}

Answer (score 0):

Looks like network error, you can try:

check internet access.

if you are behind a proxy check this answer for npm proxy settings [proxy settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559648/is-there-a-way-to-make-npm-install-the-command-to-work-behind-proxy)

Clean npm cache `npm cache clear --force`

Comment: I checked my system and I am not behind a proxy.  This did not work:   npm cache clear --force.  See the updated post. I added the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Use,

`npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/`

then run `npm install`

Comment: the error is still coming up - npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET