# Not able to do npm install

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, nvm, npx

I am not able to do npm install create-react-app whenever I do it stops and after some time it gives an error. This happened after the new version of **Mac Ventura 13.1**

[image]

I tried using yarn but still failed.

I just want a solution for creating a react app.

Answer (score 0):

try `npx create-react-app` instead of `npm`

If still not working it seems like you have a problem with proxy. You can check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7559648/4064308)

Comment: Thanks for your help! But it still giving the same error. my version of npx is 8.15.0                         
sahilbehl@Sahils-MacBook-Pro ~ % npx create-react-app my-app apm ERR! code ENOTFOUND npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo apm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
hpm ERR! network request to http://registry.pmjs.org/create-react-app failed, r eason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND domain
nom ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity. npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settin gIS
apm ERR! network

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).