# Package Installation issues using npm command

Tags: reactjs, npm

whenever I try to install node_modules using
`npm i`  command or
`npm install` command
I am getting these error messages:
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
or
(node:14835) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 close listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit

for the above errors I have tried each solution setting maxListeners, setting the config as per solution given in this
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559648/is-there-a-way-to-make-npm-install-the-command-to-work-behind-proxy](https://stackoverflow.com)
despite of trying all above solutions I am not able to install and run a new project or new repository.
sometimes the npm start also terminates with a message: "Bus error (core dumped)"
Please help me out with these
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you have proxy setup:

```
npm config get proxy
```

And if yes set it null and try again

```
npm config set proxy null
```

Comment: and if its null, try "npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/"

Comment: thanks for your answer but the solution you provided didn't work. any other way to fix it?

Comment: whats your output for npm config get proxy?

Comment: can you share your /etc/hosts file content?

Comment: ok these are the details of /etc/hosts file: 
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

were you talking about this??

Comment: also now after npm i command in one of the projects the npm start command terminates by this message
 
> @minimal/material-kit-react@1.8.0 start
> vite preview

Bus error (core dumped)

have any solution for this??

Comment: Yes i was talking about the same, why you have these configuration in hosts file? this hosts file is kind of router for your computer, all your domain lookup first goes to this file.

So do one thing make a copy of this file for a safe, then update the file and try
- 127.0.0.1 localhost
- 255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
- ::1             localhost

Comment: ok thankyou the problem has been solved thanks alot

Comment: Welcome... @N__